# Summation of $c^i, i>1$.

Tags: summation, algorithms

Problem:

$$
\sum_{i=7}^{N}4^i
$$

I want to know how to find the closed form. I believe the formula is:

$$
\sum_{i=7}^{N}4^i = \sum_{i=1}^{N}4^i-\sum_{i=1}^{6}4^i
$$

Equals

$$
\frac{1-4^{(N+1)}}{1-4}-\frac{1-4^{(6+1)}}{1-4}
$$

Is this correct? Please advise.

Comment: If sums were starting at $i=0$ that would be perfect. Also it is $N$ not $n$.

Comment: No you have to start from $i=0$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}4^i-\sum_{i=0}^{6}4^i=\frac{1-4^{n+1}}{1-4}-\frac{1-4^{6+1}}{1-4}$$

Comment: Can you please show me some supporting evidence. Link an article and point to the section? Then post the answer so I can mark it.

Comment: @user2355058 the formula you used to evaluate the geometric sum is for sums starting at $i=0$, as shown by Raffaele. It still gives the same result as yours, however

Comment: A better idea would to be to prove the more general result that if $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is a geometric progression, then $\sum\limits_{k=m}^n a_k=\dfrac{a_m(r^{n-m+1}-1)}{r-1}$ where $r$ is the common ratio. Even more generally, the sum of the terms of a geometric series is given by $\dfrac{a(r^q-1)}{r-1}$ where $a$ is the first term of the series, $q$ is the number of terms in the series and $r$ is the common ratio.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to do like below 
$$\quad{\sum_{i=7}^{N}4^i=4^7+4^8+...+4^N=\\4^7(1+4+4^2+...+4^{N-7})=\\
4^7(\frac{1-4^{N-7+1}}{1-4})=\\4^7(\frac{4^{N-6}-1}{3})=\\\frac{4^{N-6+7}-4^7}{3}=\\\frac{4^{N+1}-4^7}{3}}$$

Comment: Nice answer, +1. It is worth pointing out that the answer OP has is the same - $$\frac{1-4^{(N+1)}}{1-4}-\frac{1-4^{(6+1)}}{1-4}=\frac{4^{N+1}-4^7}{3}$$

Comment: So my answer was correct as long as I do `i=0` under Sigma in the expansion? Please take a look at the original summation and let me know if its all clean.

Comment: @user2355058: you are right , but in your formula $N\geq 7$

Comment: So if I correct it to use `i=0` it is 100% correct? Or are you saying my index is still off? Does it need to be $\frac{1-4^{(N)}}{1-4}$

Comment: When your start point is $7$ , what does it men ?